# Sockets UDP TCP C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a question:
Is it possible to execute `sendto` to send information from one process which is initialized on UDP to another process initialized on TCP (this is all in the same `.c`)?.

I have one process which receives information on UDP and this one has to send this information locally to the TCP one and I don't know how to connect (I know you cannot connect with UDP, I mean just send the datagram) them.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just receive the data over UDP and then send it using TCP?

Comment: The protocol on both ends must match.

Comment: Why are you using non-matching protocols then if you want them to match?

Comment: "this is all in the same .c" , can't this be a shared variable or a global data structure or whatever ?

Comment: Two processes from one .c file? MIsmatching protocols? What is this (copy/paste) monster?

Comment: So? Send the data on TCP. What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that is receiving UDP packets has to open a separate TCP socket to send to the other process.

So at startup this process should first open up a UDP socket to receive datagrams.  Then it gets a TCP socket and uses that to connect to the other process using the `connect` function.  Then, whenever data comes in on the UDP socket, you take that data and send it out using `send` over the TCP socket for the other server to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can send udp datagrams from a UDP socket to a UDP socket.
You can send byte streams from a TCP socket to a TCP socket.

If you want to use a socket for inter-process communication, then both processes need use the same type of socket.